# How to get int value from a datagridview (with checkboxcolumn) when it's checkbox is checked?

Tags: c#, winforms, wamp

I'm currently working with datagridview connected with wamp server. My datagridview contains checkboxcolumn (1st col), code (2nd col), course title (3rd col), and units (4th col, where the int values are here) What I want know is how can I get the sum of all units that's been checked. Please help it's for my thesis

Comment: There could be more than one row with checked check box. What's the expected result in such case?

Comment: Yes, there could be multiple checked checkbox, I just need to get all the values for the computation (it's for the payment part of my enrollment system)

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in myDataGrid.Rows)
{
         if (row.Cells[myCheckboxCell.Index].Value.ToBool())
         {
             row.Cells[myCell.index].Value // do somethin to this
         }
}
```

this is how i deal with my datagridviews in my project.i hope this helps,this does not need linq included in your project.

however :

if you are trying to do the value-get thingy right after the checkbox is checked and only for that row,you need a delegate action added to the column ,which is checkedchanged.
in that case:

you need this inside the EditingControlShowing event of your grid

```
 var checkbox = (CheckBox)e.Control;
    checkbox.CheckedChanged += (sender2, e2) =>
    {
         if(checkbox.Checked)
         {
            myDatagrid.CurrentRow.Cells[myIntValue.index].Value //do something to your value
         }
    };
```

this means you cast the checkbox into a normal checkbox and make a delegate checked changed event for it,that way every time its checked your value is selected and your desired event would work.

Edit : This is what ToBool() Does :

```
public static bool ToBool(this bool? ex)
    {
        if (ex == null || ex == false)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

its one of the tools that i use in my projects.

Comment: The .ToBool() is not showing in my VS2012. Can you help me with that?

Comment: yes sorry about that its a tool of my own,simply a method,i added it to the answer.

Comment: Hows that even possible Q_Q